# View class is not receiving updated Model class data

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, sfml

## Model class

```
class spaceshipModel {
private:
Vector2f position;
float speed, acceleration, energy, fuel;

public:
//Contructor
spaceshipModel() : position(0, 0), speed(0), acceleration(0), energy(0), fuel(0) {}

//Destructor
~spaceshipModel() {}

//Sets
void setPosition(float _x, float _y) { position.x = _x; position.y = _y; }

void setSpeed(float _speed) { speed = _speed; }

void setAcceleration(float _acceleration) { acceleration = _acceleration; }

void setEnergy(float _energy) { energy = _energy; }

void setFuel(float _fuel) { fuel = _fuel; }

//Gets
Vector2f getPosition() { return position; }

float getSpeed() { return speed; }

float getAcceleration() { return acceleration; }

float getEnergy() { return energy; }

float getFuel() { return fuel; }

};
```

## View class

```
class spaceshipView {
private:
 Texture* image;
 Sprite sprite;
 spaceshipModel model;

public:
 //Constructor
 spaceshipView() : image(0) {}

 //Destructor
 ~spaceshipView() {}

//Setting the image
void setImage(Texture* _image) { image = _image; }

//Drawing the image
void drawImage(RenderWindow* _window) {
    sprite.setTexture(*image);
    sprite.setPosition(model.getPosition());
    sprite.setScale(Vector2f(0.2f, 0.2f));
    _window->draw(sprite);
    _window->display();
}
};
```

## Main

A left a lot of the code out, but I then call this in main:

```
int main() {

//Call instance of the Spaceship model
spaceshipModel shipModel;

//Call instance of the Spaceship view
spaceshipView shipView;

//Create the texture of the spaceship from file
Texture spaceship;
spaceship.loadFromFile("spaceship.png");

//Create the window
RenderWindow window(VideoMode(800, 600), "Spaceship with MVC");

//Run the program as long as the window is open 
while (window.isOpen()) {

    //Check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop 
    Event event;

    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {

        //"Close requested" event: we close the window 
        switch (event.type) {

        //Window closed by pressing the X
        case Event::Closed:     
            window.close();
            break;

        //Checking for key pressed event
        case Event::KeyPressed:

            //Pressing esc to close the window
            if (event.key.code == Keyboard::Escape) {
                window.close();
            }
            break;      

        //We don't process other types of events
        default:             
            break;
        }

        //Clear screen with white BG
        window.clear(Color::White);

        //TESTING THE SETTING OF THE POSITION
        std::cout << shipModel.getPosition().x << ", " << shipModel.getPosition().y << std::endl;
        shipModel.setPosition(100, 100);
        std::cout << shipModel.getPosition().x << ", " << shipModel.getPosition().y << std::endl;

        //Set and draw the image
        shipView.setImage(&spaceship);
        shipView.drawImage(&window);

    }
}

return 0;

}
```

The spaceship draws perfectly, but is only set at (0, 0). Even when setting the position to (100, 100) like it shows above. The image stays at (0, 0). As I'm using the getPosition function from the Model class in the View class, I don't think the data is being updated correctly, even when the cout test does show a change.

What am I doing wrong? Can someone give me some pointers?

Comment: If more code is required, just ask and I can share it.

Comment: Please post [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Updated the main code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code snippet above, `shipModel` object from `main()` and `shipView.model` are two distinct objects. You can either let your `shipView` be aware of the model using a setter in `spaceshipView`, or call `shipView.model`'s methods directly.